# gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable

Tags: python, node.js, windows, environment-variables, node-gyp

**I've removed node-modules, reinstall it, tried to install npm install --global node-gyp, cleaned force cache and other**

```
error C:\Users\me\work\proj\node_modules\sha3: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\me\work\proj\node_modules\sha3
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@4.0.0
gyp info using node@10.14.2 | win32 | x64
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Programs\Python2.7\python2.7.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\me\work\proj\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\work\proj\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\me\work\proj\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\me\\work\\proj\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\me\work\proj\node_modules\sha3
```

Comment: Have you looked at the error msg in the stack trace Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Programs\Python2.7\python2.7.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

Comment: how can i do it?

Answer (score 10):

The `node-gyp` installation instructions provide two options to get all of their necessary dependencies, including Python 2.

> #### Option 1
>
> Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) using `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (**run as Administrator**).

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

**Option 2** is to install them manually, individually. Read everything here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you need to download python 2.7 to continue at python.org

Comment: what do i need to do after that?

Comment: re-run your file

Answer (score 1):

I you use the high version of Node. Try to downgrade .

Comment: this resolved it for me. I was having issue with `v16.9.1`, I downgraded to `v14.17.3` and no more error.

Answer (score 0):

gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed:

This is due to the fact that python2 is not installed.

node gyp does not require python 3 rather python2.

Alternatively installation of node version 12 inplace of version 10 solves the issues as it installs the missing `visualstudio2017-workload-vctools...`